# Remove elements from list in python based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, list

I have the foll. list in python:

```
list_vals = ['primf_to_primf', 'primf_to_primn', 'primf_to_secdf', 'primf_to_secdn', 'primf_to_urban', 'primf_to_c3ann', 'primf_to_c4ann', 'primf_to_c3per', 'primf_to_c4per', 'primf_to_c3nfx', 'primf_to_pastr', 'primf_to_range', 'primn_to_primf', 'primn_to_primn', 'primn_to_secdf', 'primn_to_secdn', 'primn_to_urban', 'primn_to_c3ann', 'primn_to_c4ann', 'primn_to_c3per', 'primn_to_c4per', 'primn_to_c3nfx', 'primn_to_pastr', 'primn_to_range', 'secdf_to_primf', 'secdf_to_primn', 'secdf_to_secdf', 'secdf_to_secdn', 'secdf_to_urban', 'secdf_to_c3ann', 'secdf_to_c4ann', 'secdf_to_c3per', 'secdf_to_c4per', 'secdf_to_c3nfx', 'secdf_to_pastr', 'secdf_to_range', 'secdn_to_primf', 'secdn_to_primn', 'secdn_to_secdf', 'secdn_to_secdn', 'secdn_to_urban', 'secdn_to_c3ann', 'secdn_to_c4ann', 'secdn_to_c3per', 'secdn_to_c4per', 'secdn_to_c3nfx', 'secdn_to_pastr', 'secdn_to_range', 'urban_to_primf', 'urban_to_primn', 'urban_to_secdf', 'urban_to_secdn', 'urban_to_urban', 'urban_to_c3ann', 'urban_to_c4ann', 'urban_to_c3per', 'urban_to_c4per', 'urban_to_c3nfx', 'urban_to_pastr', 'urban_to_range', 'c3ann_to_primf', 'c3ann_to_primn', 'c3ann_to_secdf', 'c3ann_to_secdn', 'c3ann_to_urban', 'c3ann_to_c3ann', 'c3ann_to_c4ann', 'c3ann_to_c3per', 'c3ann_to_c4per', 'c3ann_to_c3nfx', 'c3ann_to_pastr', 'c3ann_to_range', 'c4ann_to_primf', 'c4ann_to_primn', 'c4ann_to_secdf', 'c4ann_to_secdn', 'c4ann_to_urban', 'c4ann_to_c3ann', 'c4ann_to_c4ann', 'c4ann_to_c3per', 'c4ann_to_c4per', 'c4ann_to_c3nfx', 'c4ann_to_pastr', 'c4ann_to_range', 'c3per_to_primf', 'c3per_to_primn', 'c3per_to_secdf', 'c3per_to_secdn', 'c3per_to_urban', 'c3per_to_c3ann', 'c3per_to_c4ann', 'c3per_to_c3per', 'c3per_to_c4per', 'c3per_to_c3nfx', 'c3per_to_pastr', 'c3per_to_range', 'c4per_to_primf', 'c4per_to_primn', 'c4per_to_secdf', 'c4per_to_secdn', 'c4per_to_urban', 'c4per_to_c3ann', 'c4per_to_c4ann', 'c4per_to_c3per', 'c4per_to_c4per', 'c4per_to_c3nfx', 'c4per_to_pastr', 'c4per_to_range', 'c3nfx_to_primf', 'c3nfx_to_primn', 'c3nfx_to_secdf', 'c3nfx_to_secdn', 'c3nfx_to_urban', 'c3nfx_to_c3ann', 'c3nfx_to_c4ann', 'c3nfx_to_c3per', 'c3nfx_to_c4per', 'c3nfx_to_c3nfx', 'c3nfx_to_pastr', 'c3nfx_to_range', 'pastr_to_primf', 'pastr_to_primn', 'pastr_to_secdf', 'pastr_to_secdn', 'pastr_to_urban', 'pastr_to_c3ann', 'pastr_to_c4ann', 'pastr_to_c3per', 'pastr_to_c4per', 'pastr_to_c3nfx', 'pastr_to_pastr', 'pastr_to_range', 'range_to_primf', 'range_to_primn', 'range_to_secdf', 'range_to_secdn', 'range_to_urban', 'range_to_c3ann', 'range_to_c4ann', 'range_to_c3per', 'range_to_c4per', 'range_to_c3nfx', 'range_to_pastr', 'range_to_range']
```

I would like to delete elements which have any of 5 of the foll. elements: `c3ann c4ann c3per c4per c3nfx`

```
y = [s for s in x if 'c3ann' not in list_vals]
```

How do I improve the approach above?

Comment: _Any 5_?  You mean _all 5_?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`all()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) would help:

```
words = ["c3ann", "c4ann", "c3per", "c4per", "c3nfx"]   
y = [s for s in list_vals if all(word not in s for word in words)]
```

Or, as @HaiVu correctly noted, changing the logic to fit [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) would speed things up:

```
y = [s for s in list_vals if not any(word in s for word in words)]
```

Comment: `all` is slower than any. Your condition could be `if not any(word in s for word in words)`. Also, a set is faster at look up than list: `words = {"c3ann", ... }`

Comment: I take back the comment about set. The first part of my comment is applicable.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression:

```
import re
y = [item for item in list_vals if not re.search(r'c\d(ann|per|nfx)', item)]
```

Comment: No. Not at all. It would be *much* slower.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what you want to improve .. speed, legibility, etc.

Maybe you want something like that:

```
res = filter(lambda word: 'c3ann' not in word, list_vals)
```